# Session Tracking

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where i want user to be logged in with his id only on one machine. I thought of using a Flag in db something like isLoggedIn = true or false. So next time when user logs in from some other machine and i go and check his credentials in DB and i can check the flag as well if the session is already opened or not.

Disadvantage of this approach is when logging out i have to go to database everytime and set that flag to false. Is there are better approach where i don't have to go to server side and can only validate it on client side if its a different machine as well but same user id?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sensible way to enforce this draconian rule is on the server-side. Think about it: it is not exactly secure to have an architecture where clients know about other clients' existence; to have clients know about other clients' current login status or activity is even worse. The only party that should know about all clients is the server.

Setting a "logged in" flag for each user in the database is problematic, because a user who forgets to log out will forever be unable to log in again.

Nevertheless, two potential solutions to this draconian requirement:

1. Store the `lastActiveTime`, `IP` and `port` of the client upon user login. In your client-side code, periodically make "keep session alive" calls to server to update `lastActiveTime`. If another client tries to login or perform an action using the same user account with a different IP and port, deny it until `lastActiveTime` exceeds a threshold timing (say, after 10 min). Upon logout or after the first client times out, clear the `lastActiveTime`, `IP` and `port` of the client in order to allow the process to start again.
2. Store IP and port of client. When another client comes knocking, rather than make him wait for the other client to timeout, kick out the first client - stop and clear the user session, start a fresh session with the second client.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario has one important issue - if client "forgot" to update db (set your boolean variable to false) - you can't login next time - for example it can happen in case of client has power failure and hard reboot/shutdown.

Better approach (but not perfect) - you can save your client's IP address.